# Mutiple plots in a single window

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I need to draw many such rows (for a0 .. a128) in a single window. I've searched in `FacetGrid`, `PairGrid` and all over around but couldn't find. Only `regplot` has similar argument `ax` but it doesn't plot histograms. My data is 128 real valued features with label column [0, 1]. I need the graphs to be shown from my Python code as a separate application on Linux.

[image]

Also, it there a way to scale this histogram to show relative values on Y such that the right curve is not skewed?

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Result")
g.map(plt.hist, "a0", bins=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your environment and data looks like. Using matplotlib's subplot it's easy. FacetGrid might work, depending on your dataframes. In regards to your normalization: matplotlib.hist takes ```density=True``` and you should be able to post this to seaborn too.

Comment: Updated the answer. Do you have an example how to use a few FacetGrid's with subplot? I've failed to pas subplot's axis there.

Comment: FacetGrid should replace subplot (does the whole subplot-thingy) as far as i know. **Edit:** Ah, you want subplots of FacetGrids... ouch... check out the docs. I think FacetGrid is a figure-object (not an axis object!) and you will run into problems.

Comment: I want just the shortest solution and I thought it can be done with seaborn. Looks like it will be numpy.histogram() then put on a manual plot from any library, so far.

Comment: No need to use np.hist. Just build a grid with plt.subplots or any other function and fill those with plt.hist. FacetGrid can do that too, if your dataframes are set up correctly i suppose. But there is not much info about your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple example using matplotlib. The code is not optimized (ugly, but simple plot-indexing):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5

data = np.random.normal(size=(N*N, 1000))

f, axarr = plt.subplots(N, N)  # maybe you want sharex=True, sharey=True

pi = [0,0]
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    if pi[1] == N:
        pi[0] += 1  # next row
        pi[1] = 0   # first column again

    axarr[pi[0], pi[1]].hist(data[i], normed=True)  # i was wrong with density;
                                                    # normed=True should be used

    pi[1] += 1

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]